# How to set `(prefers-reduced-motion: reduce)` to chromedriver from Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to emulate the setting `prefers-reduced-motion: reduce` available in CSS/JS but with chromedriver/capybara.

It's a Ruby on Rails app with minitest tests.

Edit:

I tried:

```rb
  setup do
    page.driver.header "Sec-CH-Prefers-Reduced-Motion", "reduce"
  end
```

But `header` doesn't seem to be defined

Thanks @engineersmnky

Comment: It appears that this option is a [system setting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion) although Firefox seems to support this as a browser configuration option . There is [some suggestion](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/11683#issuecomment-1820106585) that you could do this through [Chrome Development Tools](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Emulation/#method-setEmulatedMedia) but most suggestions appear to be based on simply turning this feature on at the system level, testing, and then reverting the setting...

Comment: ...Finally it does appear that you could also pass this as a [Header Option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-CH-Prefers-Reduced-Motion) but this is still labeled as experimental. I can neither confirm or deny the functionality of any of the proposed options.

Comment: It appears it might be possible to use [`Driver#intercept`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/DriverExtensions/HasNetworkInterception.html) which yields a [`DevTools::Request`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/DevTools/Request.html). Usage may look like:  `page.driver.intercept {|request, &continue| request.headers["Sec-CH-Prefers-Reduced-Motion"] = "reduce"; continue.call(request)}` but again this is untested.